# Remove undefined, null, NaN from JS Object using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given a Javascript object

```
x = {'a': 123, 'b': 'hello', 'c': NaN, 'd': null, 'e': undefined}
```

Is it possible to remove all properties that has `NaN`, `null`, or `undefined` using Lodash, or without Lodash but in a similarly readable way?

Tried

```
_.omitBy(x, _.isNil)
```

but it did not remove `NaN`

```
{a: 123, b: "hello", c: NaN}
```

Can _.omitBy take multiple parameters in addition to `_.isNil`?

Answer (score 4):

Because isNil just checks for the `null/undefined` value ([doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil))

> Checks if value is null or undefined.

So you also have to check if the value is NaN with `_.isNaN`.

```
_.overSome([_.isNil, _.isNaN])
```

```js
const x = {'a': 123, 'b': 'hello', 'c': NaN, 'd': null, 'e': undefined}

const res = _.omitBy(x, _.overSome([_.isNil, _.isNaN]))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could also do that in vanilla JS.

- Transform the object to array of key-value pairs
- reject pairs that have falsy value
- transform the pairs back to object

```js
const x = { a: 123, b: "hello", c: NaN, d: null, e: undefined };

const isNilOrNaN = (val) => val == null || Number.isNaN(val);

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(x).filter(([key, value]) => !isNilOrNaN(value))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This would also remove `0`, empty strings, literal `false`, and any other falsy values.

Comment: @JustinTaddei I've just updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) to detect `NaN` and `value == null` to detect `null` and `undefined`.

```js
x = {'a': 123, 'b': 'hello', 'c': NaN, 'd': null, 'e': undefined}

const result = Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (x[key] == null || Number.isNaN(x[key])) {
    return acc
  }

  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: x[key],
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just javascript, you could use `Array.filter` on an array created with `Object.entries` then turn it back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const sourceObj = {
  'a': 123,
  'b': 'hello',
  'c': NaN,
  'd': null,
  'e': undefined,
  'f': 0,
  'g': ''
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(sourceObj).filter(([key, val]) =>
  val != null && !Number.isNaN(val)
))

console.log(result);
```

Using lodash you could use `pickBy`, `isNaN`, and `isNil`.

```js
const sourceObj = {
  a: 123,
  b: "hello",
  c: NaN,
  d: null,
  e: undefined,
  f: 0,
  g: ""
};

const result = _.pickBy(sourceObj, (value) => {
  return !_.isNaN(value) && !_.isNil(value)
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Which one has better readability is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Array.includes** will solve many problems like this.

```js
let x = {'a': 123, 'b': 'hello', 'c': NaN, 'd': null, 'e': undefined}

let result =
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(x).filter(
            v => ![NaN, null, undefined].includes(v[1])))

// result is { a: 123, b: "hello" }
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```js
const x = {'a': 123, 'b': 'hello', 'c': NaN, 'd': null, 'e': undefined}

const cleaned = _(x).omitBy(_.isNil).omitBy(_.isNaN).value()

console.log(cleaned)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```